# Getting Editext OnSelectionChange(int selStart, int selEnd) callback values in MainActivity and setting it to TextView

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have EditText in my MainActivity and i want to get the position of cursor of the editext i have edittext subclass and has overriden below method.

```
@override
protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
   OnSelectionChangedListener LISTENER = new MainActivity();
   LISTENER.update_pos(selStart, selEnd);
   super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);
}

interface OnSelectionChangedListener {
  void update_pos(int selStart, int SelEnd);
}
```

I have used interface and got the values of edittext selStart and selEnd in My MainActivity but i want to set the values in TextView on Every Selection Change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
public class CursorEditText extends AppCompatEditText {

    private OnSelectionChangedListener mListener;

    public CursorEditText(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CursorEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CursorEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public void setOnSelectionChangedListener(OnSelectionChangedListener onSelectionChangedListener) {
        mListener = onSelectionChangedListener;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {

        if (mListener != null)
             mListener.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);

        super.onSelectionChanged(selStart, selEnd);

    }

    public interface OnSelectionChangedListener {

        void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd);

    }

}
```

Then in your activity, implement OnSelectionChangedListener and call:

```
 yourEditTextReference.setOnSelectionChangedListener(this);
```

This method should be implementable in your activity now:

```
@Override
public void onSelectionChanged(int selStart, int selEnd) {
    yourTextView.setText(String.valueOf(selStart));
}
```

Comment: I want to track down the cursor position everytime the cursor changes position @AzraelPwnz's

Comment: You want the 'selected' edittext values to be shown in the TextView?

Comment: Yes i want to show the position of the cursor in a textview

Comment: Edited my answer to show: yourTextView.setText(String.valueOf(selStart));

Comment: Yes i have done as you said and now it is working fine. I was missing to add the function setOnSelectionChangedListener() in Edittext Subclass that actually worked for me. THANK YOU

Comment: I have to check if listener is initialized or not before calling mListener.onSelectionChanged() or else it will throw nullpointerexception